# A good Wordpress theme development book recommendation

Tags: books

I am looking for a good recommendation for a wordpress theme development book. i have some experience building themes, but I want to learn more, and have trouble reading or understanding the codex sometimes. I don't know that much php, so a php recommendation would also be nice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [Digging into WordPress](http://digwp.com/book/) (it covers the whole WP dev) and [Rockstar WordPress Designer](http://rockablepress.com/books/rockstar-wordpress-designer/) (part 1 and 2), both are available in e-book/pdf format.